# How to make a click anywhere on the screen close mobile menu that is controlled by jQuery toggle() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My mobile menu is opened/closed by a jQuery `toggle()` function. Besides the ability to close it by clicking again the same hamburger icon used to open it, I also want the ability to close it by clicking anywhere on the screen while it's open. However such click anywhere on the screen "disturbs" the `toggle()` function in the following way: once the menu open, if I close it by clicking anywhere on the screen then click the mobile menu icon again to open it, it works only the second time I click it (because the `toggle()` function didn't "know" that I closed the menu by clicking on the screen).

How to fix this problem?

JS:

```
$( '.header__menu_icon' ).toggle( function() {
  $( '.wrap' ).removeClass( 'mobile_menu_opening mobile_menu_closing' );
  $( '.wrap' ).addClass( 'mobile_menu_opening' ); 
}, function() {
  $( '.wrap' ).removeClass( 'mobile_menu_opening mobile_menu_closing' );
  $( '.wrap' ).addClass( 'mobile_menu_closing' ); 
});
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( '.wrap' ).removeClass( 'mobile_menu_opening mobile_menu_closing' );
  $( '.wrap' ).addClass( 'mobile_menu_closing' ); 
});
$( '.mobile_menu' ).click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='mobile_menu'>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes mobile_menu_opening {
  0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-280px); }
}
@keyframes mobile_menu_closing {
  0% { transform: translateX(-280px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}
.mobile_menu_opening {
  animation-name: mobile_menu_opening;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.mobile_menu_closing {
  animation-name: mobile_menu_closing;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would achieve that by simply avoiding the toggle function. Besides, your code can be optimized the following way:

```
function menuToggle() {
  var openClass = 'mobile_menu_opening';
  var closedClass = 'mobile_menu_closing';
  var $wrap = $('.wrap');
  if ($wrap.hasClass(openClass)) {
    $wrap.removeClass(openClass);
    $wrap.addClass(closedClass);
  } else {
    $wrap.removeClass(closedClass);
    $wrap.addClass(openClass);
  }
}

$('.header__menu_icon').on('click', function() {
  menuToggle();
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
  menuToggle();
});

$('.mobile_menu').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Using your code, menu opens and immediately closes though.

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere so I could check what is wrong in your implementation? It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Use the NOT specifier

```
$( "body:not(.mobile_menu)" ).click(function() {
    $("").removeClass("");
    - or -
   $("").toggle("");
});
```

Comment: Not sure what the "- or -" stands for in terms of logic